# После закрытия окна теряется управление над элементом

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

У меня есть два окна. Родительское(`Main.aspx`) и дочернее(`Child.aspx`). Из дочернего окна отправляю `post` данные и после получения ответа хочу работать с элементом в родительском контенте.

Доступ к элементу я получил через

```
$(window.opener.document).find("#element");
```

Но столкнулся с другой проблемой, мне после ответа от сервера в виде `json` данных необходимо закрыть дочернее окно..

```
window.close()
```

окно закрывается но после этого сразу теряется управление над элементом.

```
 $("#btn").click(function () {
        var m = confirm("Вы уверены что хотите удалить данную запись пользователя? Данные будут удалены безвозвратно.");
        if (m) {

            var Username = $("#FieldUsername").val(); 
            var elem = $(window.opener.document).find("#SysMessage");


            $.ajax({
                url: "Child.aspx/Delete",
                datatype: "json",
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    'Username': Username                  
                }),              
                beforeSend: function () {
                    elem.stop().fadeOut();
                },
                complete: function () {                    

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.d); 
                    data = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    if (data.type == "error") {                     
                        elem.addClass("error");
                    }
                    else {                                                                   
                        $(window.opener.document).find("#__Refresh").click();
                        elem.addClass("success");
                    }

                    elem.text(data.str);
                    elem.slideToggle('medium');
                    elem.delay(5000).fadeOut(800);
                    window.close();
                }               
            });
```

Причем окно закрывается сразу, хотя должно в последнюю очередь. Подскажите в чем мое недопонимание, как быть.

Comment: что значит "теряется управление над элементом"? Вы откладываете fadeOut на 5 секунд, а окно закрываете сразу. Jquery детского окна отгружается и fadeOut делать нечему.

Comment: Igor, спасибо за комментарий. Даже здесь даже не успевает  'elem.slideToggle('medium');' выполниться как закрывается окно. elem(Div) выезжает на пару миллиметров и все.

Comment: Вот, спасибо за уточнение. Библиотеки jquery (и глобальные $) в родительском и дочернем окнах - независимы. Попробуйте:  `var elem = window.opener.$(document).find("#SysMessage");`

Comment: Igor, попробовал. Теперь даже 2 миллиметра дива не показывается) Видимо теперь вообще не видит див

Comment: Выясните, пожалуйста, работает ли поиск требуемого элемента в родительском окне - `alert(elem.length);` после `var elem = ...`.

Comment: var elem = window.opener.$(document).find("#SysMessage"); alert(elem.length); вернул 0. var elem = $(window.opener.document).find("#SysMessage"); alert(elem.length); вернул 1.

Comment: Блин, вот же я :( ! Документ-то тоже из родительского окна надо брать `window.opener.$(window.opener.document).find("#SysMessage");` или проще `window.opener.$("#SysMessage");`

Comment: Igor, большое спасибо) очень признателен за быструю и эффективную помощь)

Comment: Я сделаю это ответом, так как мне до сих пор вопросы о работе с jquery между окнами не попадались.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы откладываете `fadeOut` на 5 секунд, а окно закрываете сразу. Jquery детского окна отгружается, и `fadeOut` делать нечему.

Библиотеки jquery (и глобальные $) в родительском и дочернем окнах - независимы. Попробуйте:

```
var elem = window.opener.$(window.opener.document).find("#SysMessage");
```

или проще

```
var elem = window.opener.$("#SysMessage");
```